# using basic http authentication in rails,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

Im using http auth in a rails app and I need to use .env files in order to keep my passwords secure.

I know I need use them and the .gitignore and .env file to do this, but I have no idea how to?

Comment: What is the last thing you have tried sofar?

Comment: I've tried using the github documentation to use the dotenv gem, but I cant understand the part after the gem installation... I can not even find the .env file, which I think is pretty crucial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem to save environment variables in `.env`. I think it's pretty easy to start.

Comment: I've tried using the github documentation to use the dotenv gem, but I cant understand the part after the gem installation... I can not even find the .env file, which I think is pretty crucial

Comment: Just add ```gem 'dotenv-rails'``` to Gemfile, run ```bundle install```, create ```.env`` file in root of your project then restart the rails server. Done! Now you can use it like here https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#usage

Comment: Thanks, I also found this video in the interim for anyone else! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re0OYhw0GUY